# Separate thousands with whitespace in string.xml

Tags: android

I ant to separate thousands (cast 100000 to 100 000) using string.xml, so I crated string resource

```
<string name="separator">%,2f ₽</string>
```

But it works only with comma and dot (100.000 and 100,000). How to make it with whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

String formatter for number only works with comma and dot. To make it possible, you need to use `DecimalFormat`:

```java
    public static String formatNumber(double number) {
        return new DecimalFormat("###,###")
            .format(number)
            .replace(",", " ");
    }
```

Then,

```java
double number = 100000000;
System.out.println(formatNumber(number)); // will print => 100 000 000
```